# Torch.gather from 1D array using 2D indices

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have an nx1 tensor and an nxm tensor. I want to gather values from the nx1 tensor using the nxm tensor.
For example
for input `tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])` and

index `tensor([[0, 3], [2, 1],[1, 3], [2,3]])`

output should be

```
tensor([[1, 4], [3, 2], [2,4], [3,4])
```

The indices are in the 2D matrix and the values are to be gathered from the 1D list.

How to use torch.gather/ or any torch tensor function for this purpose?
My following code gives error

```
t = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
ind = torch.tensor([[0, 3], [2, 1],[1, 3], [2,3]])
torch.gather(t, 0, ind)

RuntimeError: index 2 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 1
```

**Edit**:
You can do simple indexing to achieve this output.

```
t[ind]
```

Is this the best way to do this. I assume this involves broadcasting the input array.

**Edit**

Using t[ind] in forward pass is resulting in the error

```
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:84: operator(): block: [430,0,0], thread: [97,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
```

When I try to print tensors in the forward pass, no output is shown after the t[ind] operation. Which makes sense as **getitem** is not a differentiable operation for the loss to propagate.
So there is a valid use case in using gather over **getitem**.

Comment: Why would you want to use `torch.gather` for something you can solve with `__getitem__`? Since you've edited your question with `t[ind]`, the question seems moot.

Comment: t[ind] operation in forward pass is not differentiable. When I use this __getitem__ functionality for my tensors, I get error
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:84: operator(): block: [430,0,0], thread: [97,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html):

```
torch.gather(t.expand(4, -1), 1, ind)
```